# Implementing Dynamic options to jquery dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, drop-down-menu

I need to use a jquery dropdown menu and but the options will be coming from a rest api. It shows the static content but not the dynamic content from web-api..!!

```
$(".select").selectBox();
```

Comment: Write `$(".select").selectBox();` in `ngAfterViewInit()` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can call a function on page load.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.ajax({
   url: "api_url",
   method: 'GET',
   success: function(result){
     if (result) {
       var options = result.map(function options(res) {
         return (<option value={res.key}>{res.label}</option>)
       })
      $(".select").innerHTML(options);
     }
   }
 });
});
```